# Julia - unable to install Dates package

Tags: date, installation, package, julia, julia-studio

After running `Pkg.init()` and `Pkg.Update()`, I am still unable to load the Dates package:

Using either:
    Pkg.add("Dates")

```
ErrorException("Dates's requirements can't be satisfied because of the following    fixed packages: julia")
```

Or double clicking 'Dates' in the packages window of Julia Studio I receive the error (adding Dates):
    julia> adding Dates

```
julia> using Dates
ErrorException("Dates not found")
```

I have uninstalled everything and reinstalled but still same error. I am running Julia Studio 0.4.4  64 bit.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how up-to-date Julia Studio is. Which Julia version are you using with it? The `Dates` package seems to require at least Julia 0.3 (or a prerelease version of it) if I interpret the package metadata correctly. If you don't have Julia 0.3 I recommend to get it - there's happened quite a lot recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dates.jl` is only available on Julia 0.3 or higher. If you are using Julia 0.2 you should use `Datetime.jl` (which is no longer supported but should still work).

Julia development is moving quick, so it'd be best to upgrade to Julia 0.3, or complain to the JuliaStudio developers so they upgrade the bundled version of Julia.